# Problem with c# webservice, referencing a method and a type

Tags: c#, web-services

I have run into a bit of a problem, well not sure if it is a problem, but would like some advice.

I have developed a c# webservice in vs2010 and when I debug the service i get this error in my browser

> The XML element 'VoucherResponse' from namespace 'http://test.org/' references a method and a type. Change the method's message name using WebMethodAttribute or change the type's root element using the XmlRootAttribute.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The XML element 'VoucherResponse' from namespace 'test.org' references a method and a type. Change the method's message name using WebMethodAttribute or change the type's root element using the XmlRootAttribute.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Now looking at my code in at the actual class "VoucherResponse" i have,

```
public class VoucherResponse : AResponse
{
    public Voucher Voucher { get; set; }
}
```

And the Voucher object looks like this

```
public class Voucher
{
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string Batch { get; set; }
}
```

Now in one of my web methods I return the VoucherResponse and I am assuming that this error occurs when it is reflected through and checked.

Has anyone had a similar problem with this before, or can anyone give me some advice on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently, SOAP cannot handle methods that have the same name as their return type.
You can fix it by reading the error, and acting accordingly:

```
public class VoucherResponse
{
    [WebMethod(MessageName="TheVoucher")]
    public Voucher Voucher{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: That didnt seem to help me, I tried what you suggested and the same error occurs - EDIT: OkI used that instead on my actual web method that returns the VoucherResponse and it worked.. Thank

Answer (score 44):

I found **another case** that raises the error! Here's my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public CheckUpdateResponse CheckUpdate()
{
...
}
```

Ok, let me explain: `CheckUpdateResponse` is a structure I defined in my code, `CheckUpdate()` is a method. So, in the WSDL **.NET add automatically a `Response` suffix to the method name `CheckUpdate`**.

Et voilà: it finds a duplicate element and gives the error *"Change the method's message name using WebMethodAttribute..."*

**Solution**? I renamed the returned type from `CheckUpdateResponse` to `CheckUpdateResult` and now everything works fine!

I hope this will help someone! I lost a lot of time on this...

Comment: 2 cases in a million, I suppose... :)

Comment: Yep.. this was what caught me out

Comment: So now 3 cases in a million

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. I was trying to create an emulator for an existing SOAP service to use for testing. Their documentation showed the resultant XML including the outer object (VoucherResponse in the OP case) so I created an outer object to match, not realizing that the outer object would be auto-generated, so now it existed twice. I removed the outer class and everything worked. The service created the outer object for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but in my case; the application that I developed is web service client, so I don't have control on changing the WSDL\Schema.

The problem was that I had one web service with 17 operations, all of them are returning the same complex type, I got the mentioned error due to deserialization of the return type, because .Net is wrapping the return type for each output, and the serializer is throwing error:

```
The XML element 'XYZ' from namespace 'ABC' references a method and a type. Change the method's message name using WebMethodAttribute or change the type's root element using the XmlRootAttribute.
```

**Solution:**
I opened Reference.cs file, removed all wappered return type generated classes, and kept only one, then changed its class name to be generic, not related to the operation, it worked for me.

Comment: I had the same issue, the error is misleading in this case

Comment: Yes @DragonAce , that is why I put the solution for others to use.